# Trouble with Symfony/Twig: trying to dynamically add rows via an Add Row button, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, forms, symfony, twig

G'day all, I've been trying to do this for a while, with no joy yet.

In a nutshell: our db has up to 10 rows for a table, with each row having 4 columns. I can display them nicely using a simple HTML table. That's all good.

If I display them all, then users can enter date for none/some/all of them, the db gets updates, and it's all good.

But many users will only need a few rows, so I want to hide all but the first, and offer a simple Add Row button. This row should change each hidden row from Display: none; to Display: inline.

Except I can't figure out how to do it! I've tried all sorts of combinations.

e.g. having an onload() function that renders each later row invisible via Display: none.

Also: setting initial CSS the same way: Display: none.

Then having the Add Row button set the ID for those rows to be Display: inline.

I'm not sure if it's worth posting code, as I suspect there's a really simple solution I'm not remotely aware of.

Anybody got any clues?

Many thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, guys, I really appreciate these answers! I'll have a crack at implementing them tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript:

```js
$("#showNext").click(function() {
  var hiddenElement = $("#rows").children(".row:hidden").first();
  hiddenElement.show();
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #29abe1;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showNext">
  Show next row.
</button>

<div id="rows">

  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>

</div>
```

**Note:** `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks very much! It also gives me clues on what areas to study next. Many thanks!

Comment: Great, this is very helpful, thanks again. How do I close the question? Or do I just leave it here like this?

Comment: @EdLove You accept the answer that helped and leave it here.

Answer (score 1):

By using javascript and an ajax request

```
function AddRow()
{
     //The current count of the rows (stored in html as hidden)
     var rowCount = parseInt(document.getElementById("rowCount").value);

     var NextRowIndex= rowCount+1;
    //updating the rowcount value in html page
     document.getElementById('rowCount').value = NextRowIndex;


    //Ajax function which retuns a the required row 
        $.ajax({
                //requesting to get the required row as response
                url:urlprefix+"add_row/"+NextRowIndex,
               beforeSend: function(){ enableLoader(); },
                success: function(data)
                 { 

                      $("#addFileRow"+rowCount).after("<div id='addFileRow"+NextRowIndex+"' class='sec-container' style='padding-bottom: 18px'>"+
                      "</div>");
                      disableLoader();
                      $("#addFileRow"+NextRowIndex).append(data);

                 },
                error: function(data)
                 {

                   alert(data);
                 }
        });   




    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but I think I might be all set with the first answer. Still, I appreciate the time you took to share it!